# Display Hex Code on Page load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, onclick

The correct, working code can be seen on the replies. End result: http://www.creativewebgroup.co.uk/library/colorshareV2/palette/Android

I'm attempting to make a colour palette script.

I have this jQuery script:

```
<script>
//document ready
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.palette-detail li').each(function () {
    $(this).html('<input type="text" style="background: #' + $(this).attr('swatch') +    '" />' );
});
$('.palette-detail').click(function (e) {
    var elem = e.target;
    if ($(elem).is('input')) {
        $(elem).val($(elem).parent().attr('swatch'));       
    }
   });
});
```

Here's a basic idea of the HTML used (in the script however it's PHP driven).

```
<ul class="palette">
<li swatch="#FFFFFF">
<li swatch="#FFFFFF">
<li swatch="#FFFFFF">
<li swatch="#FFFFFF">
<li swatch="#FFFFFF">
<span><a href="palette/URL">Title</a></span>
</ul>
```

At the moment the script requires the user to **click** on a li block for the hex code to display. I want it to instead show **straight away**.

Is this possible? If so how?

Thanks a bunch guys!

Comment: Straight away - on page load (what should be shown in that case??), or on hover?

Comment: notice the bug here http://www.creativewebgroup.co.uk/library/colorshareV2/palette/gggggg

Comment: Yeah, I need to remove the # the script is adding - Good spot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<ul class="palette">
<li swatch="#4362ff">
<li swatch="#ee3d5f">
<li swatch="#FFFFFF">
<li swatch="#FFFFFF">
<li swatch="#FFFFFF">

</ul><span><a href="palette/URL">Title</a></span>
```

**jQuery**

```
     //document ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.palette li').each(function () {
        $(this).html('<input value='+$(this).attr("swatch")+' type="text" style="background: ' + $(this).attr('swatch') + '" />');
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/9QMQs/6)

There were lots of mistakes in the code. You didn't select the correct class for the UL.
Also `UL` elements can not contain `span` elements.

Also using inspect element would have showed the code does what it told it to and put ## on front of the color.

Comment: Didn't you want to apply background color on load?

Comment: Actually I think the OP was wanting the hex shown within the inputs... like this? http://jsfiddle.net/9QMQs/2/

Comment: Spot on Smerny! Just had to make one modification (adding # to the jquery). You can see it in action here: http://www.creativewebgroup.co.uk/library/colorshareV2/palette/Android